# Spock Grails 2.0 Forward Not returning Model data

Tags: grails, spock

I am trying to test a Grails 2.0.4 controller Using Spock plugin

--------------------Controller-------------------

```
def addComment= {

    def pageCounter=0

    def result=reviewService.addComment(params.copyId,params.comment)

    forward(action: "showPage", model: [copyId: result.copy.id,pageCounter:pageCounter])

}
```

==================Controller test============================

```
@TestFor(ReviewController)
class ReviewControllerSpec extends ControllerSpec
{

def "test"() {


        setup:
                       -------------

                when:
                       -------------
                       def returnMap=controller.addComment()

                then:
                       mockResponse.forwardedUrl=='/grails/review/showPage.dispatch'


}
```

---

The Test passes but i am not able to get the return parameters defined in the controller forward

```
forward(action: "showPage", model: [copyId: result.copy.id,pageCounter:pageCounter])
```

Can you please help me and let me know how to get the return parameters `copyId` and `pageCounter` in my Spock Unit Test.
I have printed the values (both the above variables) in the Controller code and they have data in them. I have looked into `forwardArgs`, `mockResponse` etc..
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

The `forward` method doesn't actually accept a `model` argument. See [the docs for `forward`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html)

You *can* use `params` in which case the values will get appended to the query string of the `forwardedUrl` that you're testing now.

If you want to pass more complex data between actions you probably want to look at the [`chain`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html) method which will put your model into flash scope before redirecting.

Comment: Is there a server-side-only way to do `chain`? With `forward` not passing any model, and `chain` requiring a client redirect, it seems that there's a large chunk of functionality missing.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, although I guess you could roll your own. I _think_ request attributes are preserved after a `forward` call so you could store the model in there and retrieve it in the following controller. It feels like you'd be making the actions rather tightly coupled, though.